# Are Python Dictionaries auto-sorted?

Tags: python

I am told to make an associative array in python, and told to sort it alphabetically. Problem is...it seems to already be auto-sorted when using this online compiler. Even when I build it in non-sorted order. https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_compiler

Why is this a problem? Because my instructor says they aren't sorted. Thus, it must mean that on his compiler, it's not automatically sorted, right? Or am I just being thrown for a loop by a really old assignment that's been outdated by updates to Python?

(Note: Why don't I just ask him? Because he doesn't have access to his email, and it's the weekend.)

Comment: http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html

Comment: Python dictionaries do not preserve the order you give them. They will sort. However, you can force them to save the order you give the using `OrderedDict` from `collections` module

Comment: Much appreciated